# Weak spark with OK coil resistances

Tags: honda, electrical, small-engine

I am having an odd behavior with a two cylinder honda gx620 engine. There is no spark on both plugs. While not really an uncommon occurrence all my usual checks have yielded no result. I did the following checks:

- New spark plug to rule out the plug
- Cut the HT lead and made a new plug connector
- Tested resistance, primary I got 2.1Ω (tab to core) and secondary I got 8kΩ (spark plug connector to core). While slightly higher than usual (max 1Ω primary, 7kΩ secondary) it does not scream no spark at all in my opinion
- Disconnected everything that could ground the coil

I can get good bright spark when I use a screw driver on the spark plug connector and hold it close to any grounding surface. It has to be fairly close, probably closer than the spark plug gap for it to happen, so apparently it is weak.

What could other causes be for the weak spark? Are the slightly high resistance values enough for having spark so weak it cant even gap at atmospheric pressure? And having the exact same behavior on both coils for both cylinders.

Comment: A coil/transformer means battery voltage,  switched via contact points. If so, did you check the contact point gap with the cam opening the gap? What condition ARE

Comment: There might have been a naming issue on my side. The motor uses a magnet on the flywheel to time the spark, it does not have points (like a magneto ignition)

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out sometimes the easy answer is also the correct answer. One of the coils was bad, the other came back eventually. Installed a new one on the side with the values I had measured above and it instantly was fine again, nothing else changed, so I guess even though the values were not that far off, it was enough.